# Разбор по составу слова "задача"

Tags: морфология

Каков морфологический состав слова "задача"? Учитывая его этимологию (задача <- задать <- дать), я пришёл к выводу, что тут приставка "за", корень "да", суффикс "ч" и окончание "а". Мне возразили так:

> > Нельзя мотивировать слово "задача" от слова "дать".
> > В слове "задача" диахронически произошло опрощение морфем, и морфемы, входящие в основу, по сути, слились в одну. Поэтому синхронически, с точки зрения состояния русского языка на данный момент, "задач" — это и есть один корень.

Верно ли это? Как узнать, слились ли морфемы в одну в других словах? Каковы признаки того, что слияние состоялось?

Comment: Совсем недавно помогала выполнять контрольную (студентке Московского института русского языка)по словообразованию, там было задание на опрощение: как объяснить разницу в морфемном составе слов задание и задача?

Comment: У слов разное значение, поэтому разные суффиксы. В САР 1789-94 (гнездо "Даю") пишется следующее :  
>Задавание - действие задающего.  
Задание - исполненное действие задавшего.  
Задача - предложение или вопрос для решения.

Суффиксы НИJ и Ч.  Такая вот разница в морфемном составе слов. Ср. : придание и придача, выданье и выдача, отдание и отдача. В первом случае продолжительное действие, во втором - факт совершенного действия.  
Задачу требуется решить (при помощи мозгов), а задание - выполнить. Однако, смысл разный.

Comment: Вот именно, что разный, потому задача- то, что нужно решить, а не то, что дали,не мотивируется этим словом и разбирается как непроизводная основа задач/а. Мне,конечно, всё равно, если просто пофилософствовать - пускай, а если для объяснения ребёнку - медвежья услуга, в школе разбирается задач/а, как и удач/а

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В слове "задача" можно выделить мотивирующую основу ЗАДА, так как задать - задача. Но это вовсе не означает, что эта основа нечленимая, при разборе слова по составу она делится на приставку ЗА и корень ДА.

В лингвистике эта проблема называется ЧЛЕНИМОСТЬЮ основы слова, и различные школы имеют разный подход к ее решению. В общем случае можно выделить РАЗНЫЕ СТЕПЕНИ членимости. Максимальную степень членимости имеют слова с ДВУСТОРОННЕЙ СОПОСТАВИМОСТЬЮ (по корню и суффиксу): летчик - ЛЕТать и грузЧИК. Сюда же относят слова со связанной основой: отпереть - запереть, включить - выключить. Меньшую степень членимости имеют основы с с ОДНОСТОРОННЕЙ СОПОСТАВИМОСТЬЮ (только по корню или только суффиксу): пасТУХ - летЧИК (по корню), бужеНИна - конИНа (по суффиксу) и т.д.

Таким образом, при разборе слова по составу мы не копируем словообразовательный разбор, а рассматриваем значения морфем, узнаваемые носителями на данном этапе развития языка. Слово "задача" имеет максимальную степень членимости: и по корню "задача - заДАть", и по суффиксу "задача - подаЧа, удаЧа. На современном этапе мы имеем приставку ЗА, корень ДА, суффикс Ч, окончание А, все они имеют узнаваемое значение. Суффикс Ч выделяется в существительных, обозначающих действие, названное по глаголу.

Материал дан по книге Николина Н.А. "современный русский язык. Морфемика",2013, учебное пособие для филологических специальностей.

Comment: София, а слово удача и задача исторически однокоренные?

Comment: Думаю, что однокоренные, удаться - удача, задать - задача, мотивирующая основа глагола "дать", приставка У имеет значение исчерпывающей полноты действия: равнять - уравнять.

Comment: А как, например, быть в школах - какой способ применять? Тот, о котором говорится в приведенном вами материале, или применять словообразовательный способ?

Comment: дача, придача, отдача, сдача, выдача, раздача, передача, поддача, подача... отглагольные существительные от дать, за исключением удачи, нет глагола удать, но есть слово уда->
удочка, удить и слово удаль. И это уже не морфология, а смысл, который не входит в компетенцию навязываемой грамматики. Это история.

Comment: Серж, в "Школьном словообразовательном словаре" Тихонова (1978) приводится словообразовательная цепочка: дать - задать - задача, и тогда вообще никаких вопросов по составу слова не возникает. Думаю, что в школе в сложных случаях (при наличии разных мнений) надо  придерживаться здравого смысла, а не крайностей. Существует инвентарный список морфем, и если они явно присутствуют в слове, то зачем искусственно  соединять их.

Answer (score 4):

По разным словам распыляться не будем, слишком места мало в одном вопросе. Однокоренные к задаче слова:  дача, отдача, удача, передача, сдача, выдача, подача, додача.

Никто на сможет оспорить общий для всех слов корень ДА, ведь разные в них только приставки. Данный критерий достаточно нагляден.

Конкретно по задаче. Она *задается* для решения кому-то кем-то. Ученику, студенту, сотруднику, подчиненному и т.д.  Кроме задачи, есть задание, в котором приставка  и корень те же, а суффикс другой. То и другое слово произошли от глагола *задать*, который явно не имеет эксклюзивного морфологического состава. Приставка за- отлично выделяется в составе глаголов и существительных: задуть, забить, зажать, задумка, заплыв, забег, загиб, запил. Значение приставки: отдельное целенаправленное действие. Так что с морфологией все в порядке, она прозрачна и всем понятна. Корень ни в коем случае не слился с приставкой, это ошибочное, неправильное мнение.  
В других словах может быть иная ситуация.

Comment: Вот только Потиха с Вами не согласен, он считает, что ошибочно как раз Ваше мнение. Кому верить-словарям или Вам? И "удач/а" не однокоренное (только исторически). Удача и задача - и вовсе разные значения.

Comment: У Потихи словарь школьный, возможно, он упрощён? Вряд ли там приводится развёрнутое объяснение, почему за 10 лет приставка, корень и суффикс "слиплись".

Comment: Вся беда морфологии, что она смысловыми переходами не занимается, а тупо пытается сравнивать наборы букв, которые грамматика назвала частями слова, в попытке навести порядок, формально, а точнее канонизировать то, что она поимела в начале, научным методом, только ученым монахам присущим. Называется это методом тыка. Ткнул-получилось, сошлось, порядок, а потом долгие рассуждения на тему..., если не сходится. А все потому, что нет вопросов: почему и как, что вижу, о том пою.

Answer (score 1):

Да, верно: задач- вся основа - корень, потому что семантика слов дать, задать и задача разошлась.

Да/ть - вручить, предоставить,   за/да/ть - поручить сделать, назначить, за/да/ни/е - то, что задали, поручили, а задач/а - то, что нужно исполнить, разрешить, появился новый оттенок трудности разрешения, связанный с мыслительной деятельностью. Дать задание и поставить задачу - смысл разный, хотя исторически от слова дать. (Ещё в 70-е годы у Тихонова было задача от задать), а вот в 80-е словари дают другой морфемный состав.

Признаки слияния - разные словообразовательные ряды: дать - дача (показаний) - выдача - данный - задание - задаток - задаточный - подача - податливый и т.д. Задача - задачка -сверхзадача - задачник.

Вопросы морфемного состава - трудная тема, в основном на чутье, но и ему доверять не стоит, только словарям, которые фиксируют изменения. Я 33 года проработала в школе, а как нужно выполнить для кого-то контрольную, обращаюсь к словарям. В основном на чутье, но частенько словарь всё же открываю: не изменилось ли что?

Answer (score 1):

Да, верно: в словарях дается основа: задач. Но в то же время как в словаре Тихонова, так и других дается разбор по морфемам: за/да/ч/а. Не совсем понятно почему. Но я полностью согласен, что синхронически, с точки зрения русского языка, в этом слове выделяется только корень-основа.

Comment: Видимо, снова борьба школ, разнобой, хотя вроде бы узаконили какой-то один, надо будет посмотреть, какой это словарь.

Answer (score 0):

Вы извините, конечно, но все ваши рассуждения - философия чистой воды, равносильны гаданию на кофейной гуще. Можно сколько угодно долго размышлять и спорить, цвет лиловый или сиреневый, или как именно выглядели первые динозавры - ни на динозавров, ни на предмет это не подействует. Как верно заметил один из ораторов, правила придумали после того, как появились слова. Никого не хочу обидеть, но за уши можно притянуть что угодно. Соль не в этом. Я так понимаю, здесь собрались люди, в основном, с филологическим образованием, либо разбирающиеся. И если уж вы спорите, обращаетесь к справочникам, и справочники тоже спорят между собой, то почему детям в третьем классе дают такие задания и ставят потом 4 или 3 за неправильный морфемный разбор. Вопрос риторический. Непонятно, что система образования хочет этим добиться.